# Why does inner method's inside execute last?

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

At following method i'm trying to get grid selected row. By the way, i use syncfusion component library.
My question when i call the grid.rowSelected, function's inside works last. So i can't pass model in ajax. 
What's the reason of it ?

```
   function editPackage() {         
        var editPackageModel;
        var grid = document.getElementById("Grid").ej2_instances[0];
        grid.rowSelected = function(args) {
            console.log(args.data);*// works last*
            editPackageModel = args.data;*// works last*              
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Package/Edit",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            data: editPackageModel,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#generalModal').html(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *works last*?

Comment: I mean works after ajax.

Comment: `rowSelected` is probably called when the user selects a row. Not before that. You may want to kick off the Ajax call from inside that event handler function.

Comment: That event handler open a modal.It's true that rowSelected is called when the users selects a row. But my problem is get the selected row inside editpackage func. Order should be like this. Click edit - get selected row -  open modal - bind selected data to model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what is the situation with "grid", i assume you have that element ready before the function is called, so try this:

```
var grid = document.getElementById("Grid").ej2_instances[0];//Get node reference.
grid.rowSelected = function (args) {//Setup event listener.
    editPackage(args.data);//Pass the data from the event to your function
}


function editPackage(editPackageModel) {//Get the "model" and send ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Package/Edit",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        data: editPackageModel,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#generalModal').html(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
        }
    });
}
```